# SSL Redirect in IIS without causing the browser to give a warning

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, iis-7, ssl

I have the subdomain https://a.site.com. I need to redirect it to https://a.site2.com as site.com is no longer is in use (we have rebranded).

What is the best way to do this without getting the browser to warn the user?

**Notes**

- My DNS provided wont let me create a cname a.site.com to go to a subdomain called a. on another domain.
- I am running IIS 7

Answer (score 1):

Since the SSL Handshake occurs before the HTTP Response, you won't be able to do that, unless you have a valid certificate for both a.site.com and a.site2.com

As TristanK pointed out, the IIS [HTTP Redirection feature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732969(WS.10).aspx) will let you configure redirects for you.

The easiest way though (if you just want the root of the site to point to the other), and from a performance point-of-view, probably the approach with the smallest resource footprint is just to let the browser client handle the redirect itself, with the meta-equiv refresh html tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://a.site2.com/">
```

Comment: I do have a cert for both address. What would I do now?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Still sadly seem to get a certifcate warning in the browser

Comment: What does the warning say? Details please? Screenshots if relevant

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- a user can browse to www.siteA.com and www.siteB.com separately, without getting a browser error

The answer is that you need to use some form of HTTP redirection by the client - for example, to 301 the client to the new location.

The [HTTP Redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732930%28WS.10%29.aspx) module can probably be used for that.